# Duplicated output when counting chars in a string with Linq

Tags: c#, string, linq, duplicates, chars

I have this problem with my output of this code which outputs how many  times a character in a string is mentioned.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        string sortedString = String.Concat(str.OrderBy(c => c));

        foreach (char ch in sortedString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ch} => {str.Count(x => x == ch)}");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
Alabala
a => 4
a => 4
a => 4
a => 4
b => 1
l => 2
l => 2
```

This is the output I want to get

```
Alabala
a => 4
b => 1
l => 2
```

Would appreciate if somebody helps me out.

Comment: It sorts the str string in a alphabetical order. So if the input is "Alabala" is sorts it like this "aaaabll"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combination of `ToDictionary()`, `OrderBy()` and `Distinct()` methods :

```
        string str = "halleluyah";

        var grouppedChars = str
            .Distinct()       // removes duplicates
            .OrderBy(c => c)  // orders them alphabetically
            .ToDictionary(    // converts to dictionary [string, int]
                c => c,
                c => str.Count(c2 => c2 == c));

        foreach (var group in grouppedChars)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{group.Key} => {group.Value}");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Output :

```
a => 2
e => 1
h => 2
l => 3
u => 1
y => 1
```

P.S.
This is better then `GroupBy()` because you don't really want to keep this chars groupped somewhere but rather keep only count of them.

Method 2, add your own struct with char information :

```
        struct CharStatistics
        {
           public readonly char @char;
           public readonly int count;

           public CharStatistics(char @char, int count)
           {
              this.@char = @char;
              this.count = count;
           }
        }
```

In Main method :

```
        string str = "halleluyah";

        var charsInfo = str
            .OrderBy(c => c)
            .Distinct()
            .Select(c =>
                new CharStatistics(c, str.Count(c2 => c2 == c)));

        foreach (var stats in charsInfo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{stats.@char} => {stats.count}");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in single linq like below:

```
string str =  Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
string sortedString = String.Concat(str.OrderBy(c => c));

var result = sortedString.GroupBy(x => x)
                         .Select(y => string.Format("{0} => {1}", y.Key, y.Count())).ToList();

foreach (var output in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}
```

Comment: You can simplify the `sortedString` to: `var sortedString = str.OrderBy(c => c);` - there's no need to turn it back into a string. Likewise, you can lost the `ToList()`.

Comment: yes :). I just updated on the result part. Rather orderBy can be part of the single linq

Comment: If you want to go mad, you could write: `var result = str.OrderBy(c => c).GroupBy(x => x).Select(y => $"{y.Key} => {y.Count()}");` ;)